# each group in quick Select algorithm should be sort?

Tags: algorithm

i have a question that my teacher in his lecture for quick select algorithm he says that after we Considering  the array as groups of 5 elements;it doesn't need to sort  each group,is he correct? because when we have a group like <3,5,7,6,1> without sorting how can we find the median??? thanks

***EDITED: it is not about quick select it is about linear general selection algorithm***

Comment: also now I find this site that in step two is written that "sort the group and then find the median" ! is there any other selection algorithm that we can find the median without sorting the group before that?thanks
the site :http://www.itl.nist.gov/div897/sqg/dads/HTML/select.html

Comment: @matin1234 - yes, there is, but they're not as efficient, although they're good enough for most intents and purposes. Read the wikipedia link in my answer.

Comment: I think we must sort the group for select algorithm but it is not necessary for sorting the elements in the quick select algorithm !! isn't it?

Comment: please look at this site: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:2PhiYQ1r76kJ:www.cse.yorku.ca/~andy/courses/3101/lecture-notes/LN4.ps+Linear+general+selection+algorithm+code&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk

Comment: also it seams that the other name of quick select is Randomized selection algorithm

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is the Median, then sorting it first could be more expensive than simply running a half-version of a selection sort, depending on your sort algorithm. In an array of n elements, you know the median will be the middle (n/2+1) element if n is odd, or the average of the two middle elements (n/2, n/2+1) if even. So perform a normal selection sort, but instead of running the entire O(N) operation, run it only halfway to obtain that selected median value.

You could also do the very easy Bubble Sort, but only run it n/2 times. This will ensure the median is in the middle, and is conceptually easy. Do it manually on paper if you doubt it.

Comment: No, running half of selection sort (`O(n^2)`) is much slower than running a full good quicksort (`O(n log n)`), which is much slower than running a selection algorithm (`O(n)`).

Comment: Yeah, I didn't mean an actual selection sort, but where you simply handpick each minimum value in order, until you reach n/2 and have the median.

Comment: that is still `O(n^2)` with a naive implementation and `O(n log n)` using a heap. Still not better than even a good quicksort.

Answer (score 0):

The median is the `floor(n / 2) + 1`th smallest element in sorted order, which the [selection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) can find in `O(n)` (considering `n` to be odd for convenience). So if you know that all the elements to the left of `k` are smaller than `k` and all the ones to the right are bigger than `k` and `k` is in position `floor(n / 2) + 1`, then you know that `k` is the median. You don't need to sort.

For example:

`8 3 11 20 18` => `11` is the median because it's in the middle and smaller than everything after it and bigger than everything before it. No sorting required.

There are many variants of the selection algorithm. The basic idea is the same for all of them, but some details might be different. Post your teacher's implementation and try to clarify your question if you need more localized help.

Comment: ok but now I have found something in this site==>http://www.itl.nist.gov/div897/sqg/dads/HTML/select.html

and in this is written that sort and then find the median?why?

Comment: @matin1234 - because that's one way (and a very good one at that, but also pretty complicated) of implementing the selection algorithm. It's called quick select and it guarantees that the worst case running time is `Theta(n)`. Doing it like that ensures this complexity. The proof is pretty hard and as for how the author of the algorithm thought about it, I have no idea. You should understand how it works, and if you don't want to take its correctness for granted, read the proof.